# C2 compileThread takes long time, and the k8s pod 's cpu up to 100%

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, jvm, jvm-codecache

some the k8s pod's cpu  suddenly increase to 100% ,   and i find out the C2 compileThread takes long time;

```
"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6c9416b800 nid=0xf runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

the codecache is not full, but reduce a lot;  and service is normal;

codecache:

[image]

i  restart the pod,  but  after some day, it happens again;

how can i solve the problem ? why ??

Comment: What happens if you DON'T restart the pod?  Does the CPU usage drop back to normal after a few minutes?  Hours?   This could just be "normal behavior" when you run a Java large application in a pod with insufficient resources (e.g. cores) ... and the JIT compiler gets busy.

Comment: The thread dump line showing the C2 thread state doesn't reveal anything or indicate any abnormal activity.

Comment: If something is actually wrong, you will need to investigate what the JIT compiler is doing.  See https://theboreddev.com/java-jit-compiler-explained-part-1/ for some hints on what to look for.  Start by turning on JIT compiler logging ....

Comment: Thanks a lot;  if dont't restart the pod, the cpu usage will not drop back to normal ater a few days, it keeps in high level ;   and the codecache keeps falling.